# Is popcorn FX plugin for Unity compatible with webGL?

Tags: web-development, website-design, web-applications, web-services

Is popcornFX plugin for Unity compatible with WebGL? If not, is there a way to get it compatible on a web browser?

Comment: Is this a browser plugin or something you install on the web server? If it is a browser plug-in, then this is not the right site for your question. Sorry. We deal in webmastering issues as it relates to the server, search, social media, how a web masters code is presented in a browser, etc. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for the moment. We are planning on porting PopcornFX to WebGL, but this is a long-term goal and this feature will not be available any time soon.